# Remove Double Quotes around the String in CSV file

Tags: csv, angular-ui-grid, double-quotes

I am using Angular UI-grid to display data in tabular form and i also added a functionality to export the visible data in CSV file but my problem is that in exported file all the string are enclose with double quotes.

Can anyone tell me how to remove those unnecessary double-quotes ?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior that you are referring to comes from the function formatFieldAsCsv(field) within the uiGridExporterService service. There is no API that will allow you to change this with a setting.

What we can do however is use a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) to override this default behavior without having to modify the ui-grid module itself.

I have demonstrated this in a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8qskcFt7EHSlTQFo4ZUG?p=preview).

In the snippet below, I have assigned *qualifier* to replace the quotations that were initially in use. With this, you can either leave the function as is and have no qualifier at all, or you can change it's value to whatever you like, and that will become the prefix/suffix of each field.

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('uiGridExporterService', [
        '$delegate',
        function myServiceDecorator($delegate) {
            $delegate.formatFieldAsCsv = formatFieldAsCsv;
            return $delegate;
        }
    ]);

    function formatFieldAsCsv(field) {

        var qualifier = '';

        if (field.value === null) { // we want to catch anything null-ish, hence just == not ===
            return '';
        }
        if (typeof(field.value) === 'number') {
            return field.value;
        }
        if (typeof(field.value) === 'boolean') {
            return (field.value ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE');
        }
        if (typeof(field.value) === 'string') {
            return qualifier + field.value.replace(/"/g, '""') + qualifier;
        }

        return JSON.stringify(field.value);
    }

}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8qskcFt7EHSlTQFo4ZUG?p=preview